# отображение памяти устройства в оперативной памяти под Linux

Tags: c, память

какие есть способы? 
ищу какие есть способы решения данной проблемы для того, чтоб выбрать оптимальный метод...
язык СИ.

Comment: в пользовательском пространстве — просто `mmap()` файла-устройства. На стороне ядра — DMA (за подробностями смотри любой букварь по теме).

Answer (score 0):

Взаимодействие с устройствами В/В может идти либо через порты В/В, либо через память устройства. Ни тот ни другой механизм в пространстве пользователя не доступны.

В драйвере, для того, что бы работать с памятью устройства необходимо выполнить два действия:

1. Выделить в ядре область памяти, которая в дальнейшем будет трактоваться ядром, как память устройства. Это делается с помощью *request_mem_region()* из kernel API.
2. Затем надо связать выделенную память с памятью устройства, что бы они стали одним целым. Это делается с помощью функуции  *ioremap()*.